# Incomprehensible Error Using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, xml, npoi

I'm trying to edit an excel file using NPOI in C#, but it's giving me an error I don't understand, and I could'nt find any documentation on the Internet for this.
Here is the relevant code :

[image]

The code is a poor quality image because SO wouldn't let me post my properly indented code, and I was tired of it. Couldn't make it work so I took a screenshot.

I always have an ugly, endless error on the 8th line, the workBook.Write instruction :

> InvalidOperationException: Type NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.ItemChoiceType is
>   missing enumeration value 'empty' for element 'empty from namespace
>   'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'Item'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_Property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_CustomProperties'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides,
>   System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute
>   root, System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type)
>   NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument..cctor () Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument
>   NPOI.POIXMLProperties..cctor () Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for NPOI.POIXMLProperties
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties () Rethrow as POIXMLException
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties () NPOI.POIXMLDocument.Write
>   (System.IO.Stream stream) Statistiques.Save () (at
>   Assets/Scripts_Exp/Statistiques.cs:26) TutorialManager.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts_Exp/TutorialManager.cs:78)

And, of course, the given URL does not exist anymore.
If i try to Console.log a given cell in the file, it gives me the correct value, so reading the file works but not writing.

Is there anyone who has already been through this ?
Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

try writing to different stream - in pseudo code:

var outputStream = new FileStream(differentPathThanInput)
workbook.Write(outputStream)